# php mail sending blank content on some servers

Tags: php, email, server

I created a class to simplify the use of `mail()` (with the possibility to add attachments, switch between text and html mode etc).

I'm currently facing this problem :

- When I try to send a mail from my local server (xampp), everything works fine.
- When I try to send a mail from a *real* apache server, the mail is correctly sent, but **the content is empty**. Everything else is fine, though (sender, recipient, CC, ...).

From the SO questions about this kind of issues, I think that it is related to CRLF, but I can't find exactly where the problem is (and none of the SO questions helped).

This is an example of how I use it :

```
<?php
    $mail = new Mail();
    $mail->from('** adress **', '** name **');
    $mail->addTo($user->mail);
    $mail->addCC('** CC adress **', '** name **');

    $mail->html = true;
    $mail->subject = '** subject of the mail **';
    $mail->content = '** HTML code **'; // This HTML is valid
    $mail->send();
```

And here is the class :

```
<?php
define('CRLF', "\r\n");

// This is used to send mail
class Mail extends Controller
{
    // Boundary
    private $boundary = null;

    // Recipients, RFC 2822
    public $to = [];
    // Subject of the mail, RFC 2047
    public $subject = '';

    // Content of the mail
    public $message = '';
    // Content is HTML ?
    public $html = false;
    // Attachments
    public $attachments = [];

    // Additional headers
    public $headers = [];

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->boundary = '_'.md5(uniqid(rand())).'_';
        $this->headers = [
            'MIME-Version' => '1.0',
            'Content-Type' => 'multipart/mixed; boundary="'.$this->boundary.'"'
        ];
    }

    public function addTo($mail, $name = null)
    {
        $this->to[] = ($name ? $name.' ' : '').'<'.$mail.'>';
        return $this;
    }

    public function from($mail, $name = null)
    {
        $this->headers['From'] = ($name ? $name.' ' : '').'<'.$mail.'>';
        return $this;
    }

    public function replyTo($mail, $name = null)
    {
        $this->headers['Reply-to'] = ($name ? $name.' ' : '').'<'.$mail.'>';
        return $this;
    }

    public function addCC($mail, $name = null)
    {
        $this->headers['Cc'][] = ($name ? $name.' ' : '').'<'.$mail.'>';
        return $this;
    }

    public function addBC($mail, $name = null)
    {
        $this->headers['Bcc'][] = ($name ? $name.' ' : '').'<'.$mail.'>';
        return $this;
    }

    public function addAttachment($fileName, $name = null)
    {
        $this->attachments[] = [$fileName, ($name === null ? pathinfo($fileName, PATHINFO_FILENAME) : $name)];
        return $this;
    }

    public function send()
    {
        // Add main content
        $fullMessage = '--'.$this->boundary.CRLF.
            'Content-Type: '.($this->html ? 'text/html' : 'text/plain').'; charset=UTF-8'.CRLF.CRLF.
            $this->content;

        // Attachments
        foreach ($this->attachments as $attachment)
        {
            if (!is_readable($attachment[0]))
                throw new Exception('Cannot read file "'.$attachment[0].'"');
            $fullMessage .= CRLF.CRLF.'--'.$this->boundary.$thids->nl.
                'Content-Type: '.mime_content_type($attachment[0]).'; name="'.$attachment[1].'"'.CRLF.
                'Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64'.CRLF.
                'Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$attachment[0].'"'.CRLF.CRLF.
                chunk_split(base64_encode(file_get_contents($attachment[0]))).CRLF;
        }

        // Adding the headers
        $fullHeaders = '';
        foreach ($this->headers as $name => $content)
        {
            if (is_array($content))
                $fullHeaders .= $name.': '.implode(', ', $content).CRLF;
            else
                $fullHeaders .= $name.': '.$content.CRLF;
        }

        return mail(implode(',', $this->to), utf8_decode($this->subject), $fullMessage, $fullHeaders);
    }
}
```

Comment: Consider checking you testing and production environment configuration.  
Maybe there is a difference in a php build

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem came from `\r\n` and `\n`.
I solved it by replacing all the `\r\n` in the content of the mail by `\n` (not in the headers).